# ES6 Arrow Function Compile Error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

This code does not compile as expected, but looking at examples around the web in should.

```
ERROR in ./src/main/javascript/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (66:18)

  64 |     }
  65 | 
> 66 |     addErrorAlert = (title, message) => {
     |                   ^
  67 |         this.state.toastContainer.error(
  68 |             message,
  69 |             title,
```

The method in question, it is actually part of a EM6 class extending React.Component

```
addErrorAlert = (title, message) => {
    this.state.toastContainer.error(
        message,
        title,
        {
            timeOut: 10000,
            extendedTimeOut: 10000,
            preventDuplicates: true,
            positionClass: "toast-bottom-full-width",
            showMethod: "fadeIn",
            hideMethod: "fadeOut"
        }
    );
};
```

WebPack config

```
var path = require('path');

var node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/javascript/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'stompjs': node_dir + '/stompjs/lib/stomp.js',
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the `addErrorAlert` function supposed to return anything or is that an action?

Comment: It is just an action, but I may want to update the state. I thought the arrow functions were a way to avoid the this.method = this.method.bind(this) as that can get annoying after a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature ([class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)) is still an experimental feature and is not include in React and ES2015 presets.

To transpile it with babel, you need to include the relevant transform in the Babel configuration.

**UPDATE:** Here's how you can enable it: first, install the NPM package `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` and change your webpack config to:

```
query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
    plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
}
```

Comment: It not very useful to through a link at a user and essentially say, "read this". Try to explain it here for OP

Comment: @m_callens I don't think I'm supposed to link the installation steps present in the site, they are very clear already. I answered clearly that this feature is not included in the presets he's using and did not simply say "read this".

Comment: Yes perhaps, but that offers no resolution.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for a resolution. Being picky about the answer when the question is vague also isn't that useful @m_callens

Comment: here's also the code which made it work in babel config `{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}`
Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), which is not part of ES6.

```
presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
```

Or you can just assign the property in the constructor.

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.addErrorAlert = () => { }
}
```